# How To Determine Which Tab In Internet Explorer Causes High CPU Usage?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, cpu-usage, task-manager

I have high CPU usage in one of a few **iexplore.exe *32** processes that i see in Windows Task Manager. Is there a way to identify which tab causing CPU spikes just like it is possible in Chrome?

*Windows 7 64-bit Enterprise*
*Internet Explorer 9.0.8112*

Answer (score 4):

*[I would have replied to Anonymous Coward (Feb 19 2014), but don't have the requisite Reputation.]*

I imagine Anonymous Coward intended to say *"suspended the high CPU usage iexplore.exe in Process **Explorer**"* (rather than *"Process **Monitor**"*).  This is the first helpful answer I've ever found on this question to discover the high CPU tab **without having to close tabs**, and it works well in IE11 (and presumably IE9 and IE10).

IE11 also has a "Performance dashboard" that can be activated on each tab via Ctrl+Shift+U to view Paint time, Frame rate, Memory, & CPU usage for each tab.  This will allow finding the high CPU tab, but it is kind of a slow process to open it for each of 20-30 tabs when CPU usage is at 100%.

Suspending the high CPU tab(s) from within Sysinternals Process Explorer is typically much quicker and allows a better functioning machine for whatever other steps may be useful [e.g., enabling Performance dashboard for tabs or closing the offending tab(s)] and allows Resuming the offending tab(s) instead of closing, if wanted.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: There is actually an answer buried in here that's not covered by other answers: ctrl+shift+u

Answer (score 3):

As a test, I suspended the high CPU usage `iexplore.exe` in Process Monitor, then went through the tabs in each IE8 to find the frozen ones. This process could probably be simulated with program that suspends `iexplore.exe` with highest CPU usage over few seconds, then sends some window message that IE should normally respond back to each of the processes. The one that doesn't respond was the frozen one and then you could unfreeze it and query the window title or something like that.

A short and sweet autohotkey_l ahk script to do this might be interesting exercise. I just have too much on my plate already.

Answer (score 2):

Try closing tabs one-at-a-time. Whichever one you close that causes the CPU to stop spiking is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the iexplore.exe *32 process that has the high cpu usage and hit the "end process" button, it will close the offending tab.

Hopefully you can see which tab was closed by watching IE, this will work unless you have too many tabs open making it difficult to observe.